# How to print the licenses used in my project using Go Modules?

Tags: go, go-modules

For legal reasons, I need a list of licenses (e.g. MIT, Apache) the dependencies (direct and transient libraries) my project uses. I only know [how to print a list of dependencies without licenses](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages_or_modules).

Is there a way to print a list of dependencies with licenses for Go Modules? Similar to what is done in npm ([NPM License Checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/license-checker)) and Gradle ([Gradle License Report](https://github.com/jk1/Gradle-License-Report)).
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried github.com/google/go-licenses?

Run

```
go get -v github.com/google/go-licenses
go build github.com/google/go-licenses
./go-licenses csv .
```

That gives you some information at least.

A bit more verbosity:
So I create a test project:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    log.Warn("Warn")
    foo := make(map[string]bool)
    foo["bar"] = true
    j, _ := json.MarshalIndent(foo, " ", " ")
    fmt.Println(string(j))
}
```

The I do:

```
me@dattan:~/testing/blabla$ go mod init example.com/test
go: creating new go.mod: module example.com/test
me@dattan:~/testing/blabla$ go build
go: finding module for package github.com/sirupsen/logrus
go: downloading github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.5.0
go: found github.com/sirupsen/logrus in github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.5.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20190422165155-953cdadca894
me@dattan:~/testing/blabla$ go get -v github.com/google/go-licenses
go: downloading github.com/google/go-licenses v0.0.0-20200227160636-0fa8c766a591
... [lots of downloads, that's why -v to see it's not dead]
github.com/google/go-licenses
me@dattan:~/testing/blabla$ go build github.com/google/go-licenses
me@dattan:~/testing/blabla$ ./go-licenses csv .
E0406 23:03:48.578291   32389 library.go:108] Failed to find license for example.com/test: no file/directory matching regexp "^(LICEN(S|C)E|COPYING|README|NOTICE)(\\..+)?$" found for /home/me/testing/blabla
E0406 23:03:48.627889   32389 csv.go:84] Error discovering URL for "/home/me/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20191119060738-e882bf8e40c2/LICENSE":
- unsupported package host "golang.org" for "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
example.com/test,Unknown,Unknown
github.com/sirupsen/logrus,https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/master/LICENSE,MIT
golang.org/x/sys/unix,Unknown,BSD-3-Clause
```

And those last lines there, not perfect but it does see that logrus is MIT and provide the link to the license. My test package lacking a LICENSE file fails of course.

**Edit from comment**
While the above worked for me these are the commands the asker needed to do:

```
go build ./... 
./go-licenses csv ./...
```

Comment: Error: errors for ["PATH_TO_PROJ"]:
PATH_TO_PROJ: -: no Go files in PATH_TO_PROJ
Usage:
  licenses csv <package> [flags]

does it support Go Modules?

Comment: Are you invoking go-licenses as explained in the README ?

Comment: I can't find an example there for a local project. there's one for a github url though but I need for a local project (with Go Modules which they also don't mention)

Comment: @LuísSoares i added a bit more, did it help?

Comment: I was able to run with similar commands (maybe you can edit)
go build ./...
....
./go-licenses csv ./...

Comment: FYI, it fails is most licences but for better results, it would need to use some GitHub API, I guess.

Comment: sorry to hear that, I only played around with it a while back and had ok-ish results. I guess it also comes down to how well formatted the licences are, that they have license files etc

Comment: typically license checkers use a % match against the license file to figure out the license type. Licenses at times are modified, so if a user modifled Apache 2.0 license, then an exact or even a 95% match won't be able to identify the license type successfully. Public GOPROXY such as https://search.gocenter.io/ also displays license information. There will be something released this month that will further make it easy to access this information.